# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE while inserting a result set from a query

Tags: mysql, resultset, insert-update, duplicates

I am querying from tableONE and trying to insert the result set into tableTWO. This can cause a duplicate key error in tableTWO at times. So i want to `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with the NEW determined value from the tableONE result set instead of ignoring it with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE columnA = columnA`.

```
INSERT INTO `simple_crimecount` (`date` , `city` , `crimecount`)(
    SELECT 
        `date`, 
        `city`,
        count(`crime_id`) AS `determined_crimecount`
    FROM `big_log_of_crimes`
    GROUP BY `date`, `city`
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `crimecount` = `determined_crimecount`;
# instead of [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `crimecount` = `crimecount`];
```

It returns an error saying the following

```
Unknown column 'determined_crimecount' in 'field list'
```

Comment: so the alias doesn't work. Use `count(crime_id)`?

Comment: says `Invalid use of group function`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that in the duplicate key clauses you cannot use any grouping functions (such as `COUNT`. However, there is an easy way around this problem. You just assign the result of the `COUNT(crime_id)` call to a variable, which you *can* use in the duplicate key clauses. Your insert statement would then look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `simple_crimecount` (`date` , `city` , `crimecount`)(
    SELECT 
        `date`, 
        `city`,
        @determined_crimecount := count(`crime_id`) AS `determined_crimecount`
    FROM `big_log_of_crimes`
    GROUP BY `date`, `city`
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `crimecount` = @determined_crimecount;
```

I have create an SQL Fiddle that shows you how it works: **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/49dda/1)**

---

You could also use `UPDATE crimecount = VALUES(crimecount)` and no variables:

```
INSERT INTO `simple_crimecount` (`date` , `city` , `crimecount`)(
    SELECT 
        `date`, 
        `city`,
        count(`crime_id`) AS `determined_crimecount`
    FROM `big_log_of_crimes`
    GROUP BY `date`, `city`
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `crimecount` = VALUES(crimecount);
```

See the **[SQL-Fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a814e/1)**

Comment: PERFECT :) .... However, in the SQL Fiddle, i think you forgot to add `date` , `city` AS the PRIMARY KEY... `ALTER TABLE `simple_crimecount` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`date` , `city`);` otherwise, it's not finding any DUPLICATE KEY at all... I am editing your answer with the update SQLfiddle.... thanks man :)

Comment: You're welcome! I *did* forget to add the primary key, feel free to edit my post.

Comment: You can also use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE crimecount = VALUES(crimecount)`. See the **[Fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a814e/1)**

Comment: hey @ypercube, thanks for the update.... your update is worth being posted as a separate answer.... I think fiddle2 is the more recommended way to do such an update in case of a `ON DUPLICATE KEY` according to the MySQL developer documentation - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values

Comment: When using the first approach with setting a variable in the select statement (`@determined_crimecount := count(crime_id)`) I get the following warning in MySQL 8.0.16: `1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'` - for this reason, I opted with using the second approach by  using `VALUES(crimecount)` in the update. This worked correctly and I safely avoided deprecation warnings. +1 for your helpful answer.