# "Invalid use of group function" when insert on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-update

I have trouble with my query which I want to insert and update while it is duplicate, but it said "Invalid use of group function" instead.

I have run my only "Select" statement and there was no issue like "Invalid use of group function".

here is my full code :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_biir_aktual(cabang_kode, periode_thn, periode_bln, pending_pp_volume, pending_pp_value)
SELECT a.cabang_kode, YEAR(a.tanggal) AS tahun, MONTH(a.tanggal)AS bulan, 
    SUM(a.qty_pending*a.unit_barang)AS tonase_pending, SUM(a.value_pending)AS value_pending 
FROM tbl_order a,
    (SELECT b.cabang_kode, MAX(b.tanggal)tanggal
    FROM tbl_order b
    GROUP BY b.cabang_kode, YEAR(b.tanggal), MONTH(b.tanggal)) AS max_cabang
WHERE max_cabang.cabang_kode = a.cabang_kode AND max_cabang.tanggal = a.tanggal
GROUP BY cabang_kode, YEAR(tanggal), MONTH(tanggal)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE pending_pp_volume = SUM(a.qty_pending*a.unit_barang), pending_pp_value = SUM(a.value_pending);
```

well,
Hey I just found this [MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE while inserting a result set from a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935896/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-while-inserting-a-result-set-from-a-query)

```
INSERT INTO tbl_biir_aktual(cabang_kode, periode_thn, periode_bln, pending_pp_volume, pending_pp_value)
SELECT a.cabang_kode, YEAR(a.tanggal) AS tahun, MONTH(a.tanggal)AS bulan, 
    @tonase_pending := SUM(a.qty_pending*a.unit_barang)AS tonase_pending, @value_pending := SUM(a.value_pending)AS value_pending 
FROM tbl_order a,
    (SELECT b.cabang_kode, MAX(b.tanggal)tanggal
    FROM tbl_order b
    GROUP BY b.cabang_kode, YEAR(b.tanggal), MONTH(b.tanggal)) AS max_cabang
WHERE max_cabang.cabang_kode = a.cabang_kode AND max_cabang.tanggal = a.tanggal
GROUP BY cabang_kode, YEAR(tanggal), MONTH(tanggal)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE pending_pp_volume = @tonase_pending, pending_pp_value = @value_pending;
```

I've tried that and it's done.
Tq Edper for your comment anyway....

Comment: Good that you found the solution. Yeah, variable should do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the alias in your update:

```
UPDATE SET pending_pp_volume = tonase_pending, pending_pp_value = value_pending
```

Also it's more wise to use another name for your alias for your aggregate than using the same name as your existing field name like the `value_pending`. Might as well changed it to TotalValuePending, so that it would be:

```
UPDATE SET pending_pp_volume = tonase_pending, pending_pp_value = TotalValuePending
```

Comment: Tq but I've tried that too, it said "Unknown column 'tonase_pending' in 'field list'"  it's solved the group proublem but it can't find the alias field of my "SUM(a.qty_pending*a.unit_barang)AS tonase_pending"

Comment: thank you for u'r help i've edited my post and it's all done now. you just need use "@" i guess like this @tonase_pending

Comment: @Agata: Glad you found the solution. `@namehere` is a variable, in this case you put the result of your aggregate function in a variable named `@tonase_pending`.