# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - help needed

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

My problem is i have an insert that updates the query on duplicate key and it is like the one below:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE 
    (COL1, COL2,  COL3 , ETC...) 
SELECT 
    COLA1, COLA2,  COUNT(1) , ETC... 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE 'CONDITION' 
GROUP BY COL1, COL2, COL3 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COL1=VALUES(COLA1), COL3=COUNT(1)
```

THIS QUERY RETURNS AN ERROR: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function SQL

```
COL1, COD2, COL3 ARE COMPLEX KEY.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(COL1, COL2, COL3, ETC...) 
    SELECT COLA1, COLA2, COUNT(1), ETC... 
    FROM TABLE2 
    WHERE 'CONDITION' 
    GROUP BY COL1, COL2, COL3 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE COL1 = VALUES(COL1), COL3 = VALUES(COL3);
```

That is, refer to the names in the `values1` statement, not the expressions in the `select` statement.

Comment: Thank you for this answear. It's correct. Also there is another method stated in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935896/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-while-inserting-a-result-set-from-a-query