# How can I insert values from SELECT SUM into other table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, filemaker

I'm stuck and I could use a little input. How can I insert the SUM(amount) of all values of "accountKonto" of table "Buchung" into one row of the table "Erfolg"?

"Buchung": id  accountKonto amount

"Erfolg": id totalAmountAccountKonto1 totalAmountAccountKonto2 …

For each possible "accountKonto" in "Buchung", there is one column in "Erfolg", into which I need to insert the sum. At the end, I need to have one new row in "Erfolg" that should have all sums of "amount" for each "accountKonto" that exists in "Buchung". Makes sense?

It should begin like this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Buchung …
```

But how do I tell it to put each sum into the corresponding field of table Erfolg?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Gary

Comment: You tagged MySQL and SQL-Server. They are two different things. Which one is it?

Comment: It's not really clear if the rows in `Erfolg` already exist, or may exist. If they don't, a simple `insert .. select` will do. If they already exist, an `update` will do. If they may or may not exist and need to be updated or inserted, then it's a bit more difficult, but you can find a similar question + answer in [On duplicate key update while inserting a result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935896/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-while-inserting-a-result-set-from-a-query). That question has a `count` aggregation, but for `sum` it should work the same way.

Comment: Actually, it's an "epSQLExecute" command in FileMaker, but stack overflow  wouldn't allow me to use this tag ;-)

Comment: The question remains. You tagged two different DBMSes, and the solution for either may be different. Please correct this and don't use incorrect tags if you can't find the right tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should combine `INSERT .. SELECT` with [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

#### Using PIVOT (available in SQL Server and Oracle, only):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT accountKonto, amount
  FROM Buchung
) t
PIVOT (
  SUM(amount) FOR accountKonto IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS p
```

The above query produces something like:

```
1      2      3
---------------------
28.00  17.00  15.35
```

#### If you're not using SQL Server:

... then you cannot use `PIVOT`, but you can emulate it easily:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE accountKonto WHEN 1 THEN amount END) totalAmountAccountKonto1,
  SUM(CASE accountKonto WHEN 2 THEN amount END) totalAmountAccountKonto2,
  SUM(CASE accountKonto WHEN 3 THEN amount END) totalAmountAccountKonto3
FROM Buchung
```

#### Inserting that into your other table:

Just use `INSERT .. SELECT` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO Erfolg (
  totalAmountAccountKonto1,
  totalAmountAccountKonto2,
  totalAmountAccountKonto3
)
SELECT p.[1], p.[2], p.[3]
FROM (
  SELECT accountKonto, amount
  FROM Buchung
) t
PIVOT (
  SUM(amount) FOR accountKonto IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS p;
```

... or if `PIVOT` is not available:

```
INSERT INTO Erfolg (
  totalAmountAccountKonto1,
  totalAmountAccountKonto2,
  totalAmountAccountKonto3
)
SELECT
  SUM(CASE accountKonto WHEN 1 THEN amount END) AS totalAmountAccountKonto1,
  SUM(CASE accountKonto WHEN 2 THEN amount END) AS totalAmountAccountKonto2,
  SUM(CASE accountKonto WHEN 3 THEN amount END) AS totalAmountAccountKonto3
FROM Buchung
```

Comment: The columns/fields already exist in "Erfolg". I just need to fill those who have values in "Buchung".

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SQL, but doesn't `AS columnname` create new columns? The columns/fields already exist in "Erfolg". I just need to fill those columns in Erfolg where there are values in "Buchung". Say, for example there are three rows in Buchung where "acountKonto" is "1", each with a different amount, say 10, 20, 30. Now, I need to write "60" into "totalAmountAccountKonto1", then I have maybe 5 rows where accountKonto = 2, etc. Can I use the above example to do this? Thanks

Comment: Oh yes, don't bother about the id in "Erfolg", it is automatically set when I insert new rows

Comment: As "Buchung" changes, the number of "accountKonto"'s who have amounts changes every time, so do the amounts themselves

Comment: Thanks! The first part works good, so far:
`SELECT
  SUM(CASE accountKonto WHEN 1 THEN amount END) totalAmountAccountKonto1,
  SUM(CASE accountKonto WHEN 2 THEN amount END) totalAmountAccountKonto2,
  SUM(CASE accountKonto WHEN 3 THEN amount END) totalAmountAccountKonto3
FROM Buchung`

Comment: But when I try to add:
`INSERT INTO Erfolg`
 I get the following error: "SELECT statement does not match the numbers in the target"
I could, maybe enter all >100 lines "totalAmountAccountKonto1…100", but I was looking for a solution that automatically reads each the value of "accountKonto" from "Buchung" and inserts those that have values into the "Erfolg" table. Only a handful of accountKonto's which are defined in Erfolg have values in Buchung.
What can I do?

Comment: @user2691528: I've adapted the query: Removed the ID, explicitly named the insert column list. I think this is as good as it gets with non-dynamic SQL

Comment: OK, thats great now. Having to insert one line for each possible accountKonto is not pretty, but better than having to dynamically make new sql queries out of the first result.   Thanks!

Comment: @user2691528: Well, I don't know file maker, but I know SQL. In SQL, you unfortunately can't create dynamic record types, unless you have some way of resorting to dynamic SQL, e.g. via XML (in SQL Server). If you can construct your SQL statement dynamically in filemaker, then you could generate the required columns, perhaps

Answer (score 0):

The design you are using is not very good - you run out of columns pretty fast (for MySQL - approx. 4k columns, depends a bit).

I'd use design for aggregate table, similar to:

```
iteration | accountNr | sum
```

Now, to fill the table, you just do (replace 1 with some timestamp, iteration ID, link to some aggregations table, your choice):

```
INSERT INTO aggregate (iteration, accountNr, sum) SELECT 1, accountNr, SUM(amount) FROM data GROUP BY accountNr
```

Now that you have data for each iteration, you can work on it in interfaces or some pivot tables just as you wish.

Comment: the fields/columns are already there, it's only about 60-70; see comment below

Answer (score 0):

Check Pivot keyword from your db server document.  If it's not supported, you can do it in your code. Or you have to do multiple queries.