# MySQL Error Using DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, macos, innodb, sql-mode

I have a project where on a weekly basis I import several large datasets that contain incorrect data, such as duplicate employee IDs where they should not be duplicates. In an effort to flag the duplicates, I try the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE AccountDuplicates
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX EmployeeID (EmployeeID);

INSERT INTO AccountDuplicates
  SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    FirstName,
    LastName
  FROM AccountsWork
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    EmployeeID = CONCAT(VALUES(EmployeeID), '*');
```

The INSERT statement gives me errors, and I do not see what I am doing wrong:

```
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspondsto your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM EAD_UserAccountsWork
           ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE EmployeeID = CONCAT(VALUES(E' at line 36
```

In case it is relevant, I am running MySQL 5.7.12 on OS X 10.11.4, INNODB engine and mysql_mode = ''. My intent here is to identify the  duplicate IDs so I can forward them to the appropriate DBAs for correction.

**Update:** I have set the database defaults as follows:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
sql_mode=''
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

Comment: could you please provide full insert statement? because FROM TABLE ON DUPLICATE KEY looks completly wrong

Comment: I didn't realize that I had omitted one line; it is complete now.

Comment: `FROM AccountsWork` does not agree with `FROM EAD_UserAccountsWork`.  Please paste the exact statement into your Question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have not qualified correctly the "source" `EmployeeID`

```
INSERT INTO AccountDuplicates
  SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    FirstName,
    LastName
  FROM AccountsWork t
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    EmployeeID = CONCAT(t.EmployeeID, '*');
```

the `EmployeeID` located left of the `=` refers to the `AccountDuplicates` table, the one on the right refers to the `AccountsWork` table

Comment: That helped, somewhat; now I am getting a slightly different error: [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM AccountsWork' at line 35

Comment: @MichaelSheaver retry with an alias for AccountsWork , I have adapted my query

Comment: Added the aliases and got the following: [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM EAD_UserAccountsWork t ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE EmployeeID = CONCAT(VALUES' at line 36
I wonder if it may be a MySQL 5.7 setting somewhere?  I have had trouble deleting duplicates in this setup as well. I added an additional detail above.

Comment: @MichaelSheaver even with `CONCAT(t.EmployeeID, '*')`  instead of `CONCAT(VALUES...` ?? You dont need that `vALUES()` in your concat, I am not even sure it is proper MySQL syntax

Comment: Changed it to CONCAT(t.EmployeeID, '*') and still get: [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM EAD_UserAccountsWork ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE EmployeeID = CONCAT(t.Empl' at line 36
I even turned on 'Show invisibles" in y Aton editor to see if there are some hidden characters in there, and nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax looks ok, maybe there was a typing error? 
this almost works:

```
-- drop table AccountsWork ;
-- drop table  AccountDuplicates;
CREATE TABLE AccountsWork (
    EmployeeID varchar(16),
    FirstName INT,
    LastName INT
);
CREATE TABLE AccountDuplicates (
    EmployeeID  varchar(16),
    FirstName INT,
    LastName INT
);
    alter table AccountDuplicates add unique index(EmployeeID); 
insert into AccountsWork values('a',2,3);
insert into AccountsWork values(1,2,3);
insert into AccountsWork values('b',2,3);
insert into AccountsWork values('c',2,3);
insert into AccountsWork values('c',2,3);
insert into AccountsWork values('c',2,3);
insert into AccountsWork values('c',2,3);
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    AccountsWork;
-- there is no syntax errors here (your original query):    
INSERT INTO AccountDuplicates
  SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    FirstName,
    LastName
  FROM AccountsWork
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    EmployeeID =  CONCAT(VALUES(EmployeeID), '*');

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    AccountDuplicates;
```

simple insert with duplicate keys works, but "select from table on duplicate key update" does not work.

I think you need to look in this question: [INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472229/insert-into-select-from-on-duplicate-key-update)

It looks like mysql parser going crazy with this kind of queries