# Insert with on duplicate key update gives error 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, on-duplicate-key

I'm trying to use this query but whatever I do I cannot get it to work. I'm still very new to the on duplicate key update syntax, but I can't find anything wrong with it

```
INSERT INTO product_leverancier (product_id, leverancier_id, prijs) 
SELECT i.product_id, i.leverancier_id, i.prijs FROM import_tbl i 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_id=VALUES(product_id), 
leverancier_id=VALUES(leverancier_id), prijs=VALUES(prijs)
```

The error I get is this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE product_id=VALUES(product_id), leverancier_id=VALUES(leverancier_id), pr' at line 2
>   Error code 1064.

And whatever I change it's always the same error and error code.
Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off, and I don't believe that `VALUES` is used when using a `SELECT` as the source of the insert.  Instead, use that source table for the update values:

```
INSERT INTO product_leverancier (product_id, leverancier_id, prijs) 
SELECT i.product_id, i.leverancier_id, i.prijs
FROM import_tbl i 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    product_id     = i.product_id, 
    leverancier_id = i.leverancier_id,
    prijs          = i.prijs
```

Note that the alias `i` is required when referring to the columns in the source table.

Here is a good reference question which delves deeper into the syntax of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` when it is used with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

[INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472229/insert-into-select-from-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: I thought I tried your notation before too, but must have done something wrong anyway because it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    product_leverancier.product_id = i.product_id, 
    product_leverancier.leverancier_id = i.leverancier_id,
    product_leverancier.prijs = i.prijs
```